# How to remove SYSLINUX Copyright message?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, syslinux

Syslinux without modules

```
initrd.img  ldlinux.c32  ldlinux.sys  root.sfs  syslinux.cfg  vmlinuz
```

syslinux.cfg

```
DEFAULT linux
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 0
LABEL linux
  LINUX vmlinuz
  INITRD initrd.img
  APPEND loop=LABEL=kiosk rootfstype=squashfs root=/loop/root.sfs boot=loop ro quiet loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log_priority=3 vga=current vt.global_cursor_default=0
```

How to remove this message?

```
SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 20150813 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no setting in SYSLINUX that lets you do this. The only way to do it is to patch the source and compile it yourself, [as Google does (did?) for Chromium OS](https://codereview.chromium.org/1748010/patch/4001/5003). Just look for occurrences of `syslinux_banner` and `copyright_str`, and remove the calls that print them.